# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object iframe src

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I received this error while passing src value of an iframe through ASP.NET C#. Here `isrc` is a string variable:

```
Line 26:         HtmlControl   ifm = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("ifm");
Line 27:         if (cover_id != null)
Line 28:         ifm.Attributes["src"] = isrc;
Line 29:         //Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx")
Line 30:     }

    \Default2.aspx.cs    Line: 28
    Source File: c:\Users\arsha\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\hajcover\Default2.aspx.cs    Line: 28
```

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Default2.btn1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\arsha\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\hajcover\Default2.aspx.cs:28
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4984; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4971
```

Comment: Do you have a control with the id `ifm`?

Comment: yes i have an iframe control

Comment: <iframe name="ifm" id='ifm' width="100%" height="680" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border:solid #999999 1px"> </iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a control on the server side, it needs to be tagged `runat="server"`.

Change your iframe to;

```
<iframe name="ifm" id='ifm' width="100%" height="680" runat="server" 
        style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border:solid #999999 1px"> </iframe>
```

then change your code to just access the control right away;

```cs
// Next line is not needed, control is automatically available with runat="server"
// HtmlControl ifm = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("ifm");
if (cover_id != null)
ifm.Attributes["src"] = isrc;
```

...and you should be set.

Comment: oh... i forgot to set its atribute  runat="server" and im puzzled from yesterday........ thanx friend it worked for me n im new on stackoverflow and i got solution for my questiuon in just 15 minutes.....